# PHP Errors .htaccess limit folder depth

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

When I have a php error it will go through like 5 folders to get to my file. For example:
    `home\admin\domain.com\folder\portfolio`
What .htaccess attribute do I need to prevent it from showing the first 2 folders(home\admin)?

I don't want end users to see the first 2 folders in my directory since they're not used often anyway. So for the most part I want to hide "home\admin" for security purposes.

Comment: Can you clarify the question, you mean to hide the /home/admin from being displayed in your php html error pages ?  Please update the question

Comment: Yeah that's the plan. What .htaccess attribute do I need to prevent it from showing the first 2 folders(home\admin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To answer the question**

You have to change your apache configuration and change to directory root of your website because php will always report the full path ( except if you can set a chroot/jail environment )

Additional explanations about the question : http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-45191.html

But it is better to hide the errors from being displayed as it show some vital information about your setup ( not just the /home/admin ) part.

To hide the errors, you can set display_errors to off.

See  http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

Comment: hmmmm ok. I'll see if I can change directories but if not I can check logs I suppose. Thanks!

Comment: Added a link with the same question somewhere else and interesting replies : http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-45191.html

Answer (score -2):

TL;DR

Set [`display_errors = Off`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) in your php.ini, and learn to check your logs.

Longer version:

In your development environment, set [`error_reporting = -1`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting). This will display *all* errors. In your production environment, set `error_reporting` to some slightly milder level and *never* splash them to the screen.

Learn to check your logs, both Apache, and if configured to log separately, your PHP logs.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee You're right. I could've said it's impossible to exactly what you want, but opted for a different approach. But hey, even useless advice is advice.